# Highchart basic-line

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line
My code for json.php:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json");
define('HOST', 'localhost');
     define('USER', 'root');
     define('PASSWORD', 'Super_Password');
     define('NAME_BD', 'bd');
$connect = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD)
        or die("error"
               .mysql_error( ));
//    print ("no error");
mysql_select_db(NAME_BD, $connect)
         or die ("error"
                 .mysql_error( ));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Time`) * 1000 as datetime, `Current A` as A FROM `TT`")
     or die ("error".mysql_error( ));
//     echo "all good";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[] = $row['datetime'];
$datab[] = $row['A'];
}
echo '?(' . "\n" . '['. "\n";
$count = count($data);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
echo '['. str_replace('"', "", json_encode($data[$i], JSON_HEX_APOS)) . ',' . str_replace('"', "", json_encode($datab[$i], JSON$
}
//echo '('. json_encode(join($data, ',')) . ')';
echo ']);';
?>
```

But it doesn't work: when I refresh my page I don't see chart

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    echo '['.
        str_replace('"', "", json_encode($data[$i], JSON_HEX_APOS)) . ',' .
        str_replace('"', "", json_encode($datab[$i], JSON$ <----- What is this? Also missing 2 closing parenthesis ))
}
```

At the end of your `echo` you have `JSON$` which is what, exactly? Not to mention you're missing a closing parenthesis in that final `str_replace()` and `json_encode()` which includes the `JSON$`.

In summary, it appears that you have some *syntax* errors that need to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

oooo sory
missing code

```
$count = count($data);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
echo '['. str_replace('"', "", json_encode($data[$i], JSON_HEX_APOS)) . ',' . str_replace('"', "", json_encode($datab[$i], JSON_HEX_APOS)) .']' . ',' . "\n";
}
//echo '('. json_encode(join($data, ',')) . ')';
echo ']);';
?>
```

In console 0 error.

Comment: The problem is that you create string which looks like a json, but is not. So use the array() in php to create right structure and then print value by json_encode() function